# javascript setTimeout error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a progress bar that moves each 5 seconds.
Here is my code:

```
function Progress(runner, validlinks)
{
    if (runner <= validlinks)
    {
        var myString = document.getElementById('links').value;
        var mySplit = myString.split("\n");
        var ValidLinksCount = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < mySplit.length; i++)
        {
            if (mySplit[i].search("who") != -1)
                ValidLinksCount++;
                ValidLinksCount++;
            else if (mySplit[i].search("we") != -1)
                ValidLinksCount++;
        }
        var jump = Math.ceil(100 / ValidLinksCount);
        runner++;
        document.getElementById("progressDiv").style.width = parseInt(document.getElementById("progressDiv").style.width) + jump + "%";
        window.setTimeout(Progress(runner,ValidLinksCount), 5000);
    }
}
```

I call it on button submit like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" disabled="true" onclick="Progress(0,0);" value="check" />
```

It just runs and doesn't wait 5 seconds until next run, why?  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Pass, don't call, a function.

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    Progress(runner,ValidLinksCount);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, I've been busting my head to find the solution.